# How to pass self in pytest when imported function takes self as argument

Tags: python, pytest, self

Suppose i have a function stored in file.py

```
class temp_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
    def temp_function(self , input):
        self.x = input
        return input+1
```

I want to write a pyest on the temp_function

```
import pytest
from file.temp_class import temp_function

def test_temp:
    input_ = 1
    expected_ = 2
    result_ = temp_function(self, input_)
    assert result_ == expected_
```

how should i write this

Comment: `temp_function` is actually method of `temp_class`. Do you know how to call method of an instance of a class? It's completely different question does it have to be in a class and what do you actually [want to] test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).You cannot import class methods separately, you have to import the class.

code:

```
import pytest
from file import temp_class

def test_temp():
    input_ = 1
    expected_ = 2
    ins = temp_class()
    result_ = ins.temp_function(input_)
    print(result_)
    assert result_ == expected_

test_temp()
```

result:

```
2
```